# How to end results at correct place after duplication removals (xml style)

Tags: perl

I am back again with a question. I have been trying all night and not winning.

I am trying to print when a `catergory` begins, then print a `description` of the items in the `catergory`, print the items and then close the `description` for the items, only once all items have been determined, then close the actual `category`.

I am able to print the beginning of `caterogry`, `description` and `item` correctly, but I am struggling to determine when they should end.

Here is my last attempt:

```
my @Input = ("Crockery breakable plates colors width",
             "Crockery breakable glasses colors volume",
             "Cutlery bendable forks steel chrome",
             "Cutlery bendable spoons plastic white",
             "Cutlery bendable spoons steel brown"
            );

my %store = ();
foreach (@Input) {
   my ($key, $key2, $value, $val1, $val2) = split;
   chomp ($key, $key2, $value, $val1, $val2);
   my $combine = "$key-$key2-$value";
   push @{$store{$combine}}, "$val1 $val2";
 }
foreach my $k(keys %store) {
($key, $key2, $value) =split /-/, $k;
 chomp ($key, $key2, $value);
     $seen{$key}++ or do {
        print "1.Start catergory\n"; 
        print "---$key\n";
     };
      $seen{$key2}++ or do {
        print "2.----Start description\n";
        print "------ $key2\n";
      };
       $seen{$value}++ or do {
        print "3.------Start of value\n";
        print "-------- $value\n";
        print join(" | ", @{$store{$k}});
        print "\n";
        print "3.------End of value\n";
        };
        $again{$key2}++ or do {
       print "2.----End Description\n";
       };
       $again{$key}++ or do {
        print "1.End Catergory\n";
       };
    }
```

The incorrect results of this:

```
1.Start catergory
---Cutlery
2.----Start description
------ bendable
3.------Start of value
-------- forks
steel chrome
3.------End of value
2.----End Description
1.End Catergory
3.------Start of value
-------- spoons
plastic white | steel brown
3.------End of value
1.Start catergory
---Crockery
2.----Start description
------ breakable
3.------Start of value
-------- glasses
colors volume
3.------End of value
2.----End Description
1.End Catergory
3.------Start of value
-------- plates
colors width
3.------End of value
```

The actual expected results should be:

```
1.Start catergory
---Cutlery
2.----Start description
------ bendable
3.------Start of value
-------- forks
steel chrome
3.------End of value\
3.------Start of value
-------- spoons
plastic white | steel brown
3.------End of value
2.----End Description
1.End Catergory
1.Start catergory
---Crockery
2.----Start description
------ breakable
3.------Start of value
-------- glasses
colors volume
3.------End of value
3.------Start of value
-------- plates
colors width
3.------End of value
2.----End Description
1.End Catergory
```

The reason why it needs to be sorted like this, is because it will follow a `xml` style output. Not sure if this will be possible with just one loop for each key. Very much appreciated in advance.

Comment: What are the added "_colors width_" -- yet more values?  Or a new classification item? The output doesn't show them.

Comment: @zdim I updated the question as requested by. Karthikeyan.R.S I did not think that it would be relevant, but seemed it was. If you run the code, you will see the ouput, hence why I used the key name (combine) to split in the loop, I need to print parents names, then values.

Comment: @zdim, this version also shows why I used `$seen` to remove duplicates and simply append (spoon values (type and color) in this instance) to the existing layer where spoons exist.

Comment: [can't help it]  ---  "_steel brown spoons_" .. ?  really?  :)

Comment: yeah, I guess that was a horrible example *facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description fits a nested [data structure](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

```
Crockery => { 
    breakable => { 
        plates  => [ 'colors width', ... ], 
        glasses => [ 'colors volume', ... ],
        ...
    }, 
    ...
},
Cutlery  => { 
    bendable  => { 
        spoons => [ 'plastic white', 'steel brown', ...], 
        forks  => [ 'steel chrome', ...],
        ... 
    },
    ...
},
...
```

This is populated very easily. It is the printing that is elaborate, given the specific output format.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my @input = (
    "Crockery breakable plates colors width",
    "Crockery breakable glasses colors volume",
    "Cutlery bendable forks steel chrome",
    "Cutlery bendable spoons plastic white",
    "Cutlery bendable spoons steel brown"
);

my %store;
foreach (@input) {
    my ($cat, $desc, $val, $type) = split ' ', $_, 4;
    push @{$store{$cat}->{$desc}->{$val}}, $type;
}
#dd \%store;

foreach my $cat (sort keys %store) {
    say "1.Start category";
    say "---$cat";
    foreach my $desc (sort keys %{$store{$cat}}) {
        say "2.---- Start description.";
        say "------ $desc";
        foreach my $val (sort keys %{$store{$cat}->{$desc}}) {
            say "3.------ Start of value";
            say "-------- $val";
            say join '|', @{$store{$cat}->{$desc}->{$val}};
            say "3.------ End of value";
        }
        say "2.---- End description";
    }   
    say "1.End category";
}
```

This prints the desired output. Since there is a fixed number of levels in your data I've used literals for them. If there is a reason to count (use a variable) please implement a counter or clarify.

The option in [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to limit the number of terms returned (to `4` above) gives the rest of the string (as a string) in that last term, just as needed here.

Remove the comment from `#dd \%store;` to see the data structure using [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Data-Dump-1.23/lib/Data/Dump.pm)

Comment: @Jacob You are welcome :).  When you write to a complex data structure the key is added the first time. Then, when that key is encountered again elements are added to the lower part of the hierarchy for that key.  So there is no question of duplicates, hashes take care of that by their nature.  Play with `perldsc` (the first link, at the top).  The `sort` merely ensures that the order of keys is the same over repeated runs, for convenience (otherwise it may not be as hashes are unordered).

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for the explanation, I get it now!

Comment: Just some feedback, and then I will delete all my comments, but after your help on this, I managed to complete my 90 line script which successfully pulls the data from a DB and prints a perfect 46 000 line xml file!! thanks again for you valuable input.

Comment: @Jacob  Great :)  That's one biggy XML!  (A comment just in case, on my previous comment: the `sort` ensures that keys _are printed_ in the same order, not that "_the order of keys is the same_".  When we say `keys %h` they come out in any old order. There are refinements of this but the order cannot be relied on. After the `sort` they're in the same order of course.)

Comment: Thanks for that. I sat with some test code last night and I went through the hash, I fully understand how it works now.. I know perl fairly well, I just never really got my head around the hash, but now I do :D

Answer (score 1):

Changed the way of storing the value into the hash and retrieving the values.

```
my @Input = ("Crockery breakable plates",
    "Crockery breakable glasses",
    "Cutlery bendable forks",
    "Cutlery bendable spoons"
);

my %store = ();
foreach (@Input) {
    my ($key, $key2, $value) = split;
    chomp ($key, $key2, $value);
    push @{$store{$key}->{$key2}} , $value;
}

foreach my $key(keys %store) {
    print "1.Start catergory\n"; 
    print "---$key\n";
    foreach my $sk ( keys %{$store{$key}} ){
            print "2.----Start description\n";
            print "------ $sk\n";
            foreach  ( @{$store{$key}->{$sk}} ) {
                    print "3.------Start of value\n";
                    print "-------- $_\n";
                    print "3.------End of value\n";
            }
            print "2.----End Description\n";
    }
    print "1.End Catergory\n";
}
```

Updated solution.

```
my @Input = ("Crockery breakable plates colors width",
    "Crockery breakable glasses colors volume",
    "Cutlery bendable forks steel chrome",
    "Cutlery bendable spoons plastic white",
    "Cutlery bendable spoons steel brown"
);

my %store = ();
foreach (@Input) {
    my ($key, $key2, $value, $val1, $val2) = split;
    chomp ($key, $key2, $value, $val1, $val2);
    my $combine = "$key-$key2";
    push @{$store{$combine}->{$value}}, "$val1 $val2";
}

foreach my $k(keys %store) {
    %seen=();
    %again=();
    ($key, $key2, $value) =split /-/, $k;
    chomp ($key, $key2, $value);
    $seen{$key}++ or do {
            print "1.Start catergory\n";
            print "---$key\n";
    };
    $seen{$key2}++ or do {
            print "2.----Start description\n";
            print "------ $key2\n";
    };
    $seen{$value}++ or do {
            foreach ( keys %{$store{"$key-$key2"}} ) {
            print "3.------Start of value\n";
                    print "-------- $_\n";
                    print join(" | ",@{$store{"$key-$key2"}->{$_}});
                    print "\n";
            print "3.------End of value\n";
            }
    };
    $again{$key2}++ or do {
            print "2.----End Description\n";
    };
    $again{$key}++ or do {
            print "1.End Catergory\n";
    };
}
```

Comment: ok, one thing, my remove duplications are now gone, so if I have any duplicated keys, subkeys or values, they will apear again in the result. I also need to retain the push with the dashes, as in the real script, there are other values for the `value` section. So the key is used to split out a name for it.

Comment: Can you edit question with sample input for above scnerio ?

Comment: will do now. Did not add it as I assumed not relevant, but I guess it is relevant.

Comment: If it is like Cluttery will have both bendable and breakable then need to use array of hashes.

Comment: see the updated code, you can run it as is, I did not update the results in the answer yet.

Comment: @Jacob whether you need to achieve the edited output using single loop ?

Comment: It can be any amount of loops, I just need to get the result in the correct order.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, I really appreciate it. Upvoted your answer.